# laravel Model returns null on calling another function from same model

Tags: arrays, laravel, function, eloquent, model

I have a Product Model in which I have a `attribute function` which return certain data.

Normally if I call it with `Product::with(['attributes'])->active()->paginate(config('app.rec_limit'));` I get the output.

but I am not able to access that or any other `function` data in model if I do this,

```
    protected $appends = ['product_attributes'];

    public function getProductAttributesAttribute() {
        return $this->attributes();
    }

    public function attributes() {
        return $this->hasMany(ProductAttribute::class);
    }
```

also if I pass a string in the `getProductAttributesAttribute function` I get that string as output.

What can be the reason here for an empty array as output?

Comment: you don't need to use accessor, you can get attributes by `with` method. and if you want to use accessors, you need to return `$this->attributes;` in `getProductAttributesAttribute`, But I'm not recommend it. Because every time you call Product, it do eager-loading.

Comment: You can try this  return $this->attributes()->get();

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code: `return $this->attributes();` returns an eloquent object, not a collection, as if you still want to perform other queries. Change to `return $this->attributes;` which returns a collection

Note that using this means attributes are fetched for each Product Model, which can lead to performance issues later on.

The ideal way is to leave it as a model relationship, then call it only when you need it